# Openstack Neutron: Adding static Router for the router via rest api

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am unable to make `PUT` request for adding static route for the Router .

I got the following error :

```
{
"NeutronError": {
 "message": "Invalid input for external_gateway_info. Reason: Unexpected keys supplied: routes.",
"type": "HTTPBadRequest",
"detail": ""
}
}
```

and my request payload is :

```
{ 

"router": { 

"distributed": false, 
"external_gateway_info": { 
"network_id": "04901d68-eb70-410c-a2ae-e4b77d4e4641",
"enable_snat": true, 
"routes": [ 
{ 
"destination": "112.112.112.0/24", 
"nexthop": "117.97.10.2" 
} 

] 

} 

} 

}
```

And, my url is: /routers/{:routerId}

With the same routes, I am able to add static route in open stack neutron but not via API request.

Any improvements in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this below payload.

{
    "router": {
        "distributed": false,
        "routes": [
                {
                    "destination": "172.1.1.0/24",
                    "nexthop": "177.77.44.11"
                }
            ]
    }
}